# How to prefix the value of column b next to text in column c

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet containing a persons name in column A, there id number in column B and there username in column C.

There username is an email address and everything before the @ sign is their ID number so in column C I want to prefix @redcross.org.uk with the value of column b in that row.

How do i do this bearing in mind the id number is a 9 digit numeric number often starting witrh a 0.

For example if I have an entry on row 2 and cell b2 contains 030024843 then I want C2 to contain 030024843@redcross.org.uk as in B2+@redcross.org.uk

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample of inputs and desired output.

Comment: updated my question as requested

Answer (score 0):

**Two** answers:

To get the desired email in **C2** enter the formula:

```
=B2 & "@redcross.org.uk"
```

but to get a nice "clickable" email address in **C2** enter the formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & B2 & "@redcross.org.uk")
```

[image]

*(You can also enhance the formula to show a better "friendly name.)*